# Sublime Text 2 sidebar context: Vim-like key bindings for sidebar navigation

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

Does anyone know the "context" for the Sublime Text 2 side bar, or have any idea how to find the context?

I use Sublime Text 2 in Vintage mode, and along with several custom key bindings (and VintageEx) rarely have to leave the home row.  Re-binding 'j', 'k', and the likes without specifying a context carries over to Insert mode in the edit window(s) so that there is movement rather than typing j or k.  To be more concrete, any thoughts on what should replace '???' in this mapping:

```
{ "keys": ["j"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true} , "context": [{"key": "???"}] }
```

to use 'j' in place of the down arrow in the sidebar?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go.  Just add this to your Preferences->Key Bindings-User.

```
{ "keys": ["h"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false}, "context":
    [ {"key": "control", "operand": "sidebar_tree"} ]
},
{ "keys": ["j"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true}, "context":
    [ {"key": "control", "operand": "sidebar_tree"} ]
},
{ "keys": ["k"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false}, "context":
    [ {"key": "control", "operand": "sidebar_tree"} ]
},
{ "keys": ["l"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [ {"key": "control", "operand": "sidebar_tree"} ]
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, @deftOfCenter...sorry it took me so long to notice there was an answer!

Comment: I know it is a little late, but glad to help @jacob-ogre.  It was driving me crazy too.